# Dell 2950 - Can I mix SSD with spindle HDDs?

Tags: dell, ssd, hardware-raid

I have a Dell 2950 with a Perc 5/i controller inside it. I don't want to spark a debate about drive types and which is "better" etc etc. Just simply;

I would like to put in 2x Cheetah 15.5k SAS drives and mirror them for the OS. I would also like to put in 2x SSDs (exact model is still being debated) and mirror those for the data.

Can the Perc 5/i manage multiple RAID volumes like this, or do all drives have to contribute to the same single virtual disk/RAID volume, which you then split into logical volumes? If it can, is this desired set up possible on a Perc 5/i?

If I need a different RAID card (I don't want to start a shopping thread either), which Dell RAID card supports this requirement?

Also, is the throughput of a Perc 5/i going to limit the throughput of the SSDs?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have multiple RAID volumes with that controller. As long as you get drives/caddies with a supported interface, you're fine.